# $L = \{ 0^p | \, p \,\text{ is prime} \}$ is not regular

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions, pumping-lemma

We assume the regularity of $L$ for the sake of contradiction.

> **Pumping Lemma:** $ \exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ for which $ \forall z \in L$ with $|z|  \geq n$, $\exists u,v,w$ with $|uv| \leq n$, $|v|
>  \geq 1$ such that $uv^iw \in L, \, \forall i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $z = 0^p$ with $p \geq n \iff |z| \geq n$. Then, using the PL:
$$
\exists u,v,w \quad \text{such that} \quad 0^p = uvw, \, |v| \geq 1 \rightarrow v = 0^m, \, 1 \leq m \leq n.
$$

Since, $uv^iw \in L, \, \forall i \in \mathbb{N}$, this implies that each term of the sequence:
$$
a_i = |uv^iw|=p + i \cdot m, \, i \in \mathbb{N}
$$
is a **prime**. Is there a quick way to show that this is false (contradiction)?

Comment: Please be more specific about what each notation means. By "$0^p$", do you mean the number $0^p$ (which always equals $0$) or the string with $p$ consecutive zeros? Also, you may recall that no nonconstant polynomial with integer coefficients can be prime everywhere.

Comment: Yes, $0^p$ is the string with $p$ consecutive zeros.